# Convert to PDF and EXCEL from google sheet (value only) and email straighaway (2 attachments) - AppsScript

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a apps script that convert from Google sheet to PDF and EXCEL & emails straightaway with 2 attachments. My problem is, the excel in one sheet that i need to export and email as attachment is got formula inside.

My question is how to export the value & formatting, so that it is not turn up #N/A.

```
    var changedFlag = false;
var TEMPLATESHEET='M-Email Me';

function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF() {
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  DriveApp.getFiles();

  // This is the link to my spreadsheet with the Form responses and the Invoice Template sheets
  // Add the link to your spreadsheet here 
  // or you can just replace the text in the link between "d/" and "/edit"
  // In my case is the text: 17I8-QDce0Nug7amrZeYTB3IYbGCGxvUj-XMt8uUUyvI
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zgs1jzjIeaBpd5Ms7emQgxhVJBMtlEOlDNDfxlhSRiY/edit");

  // We are going to get the email address from the cell "B7" from the "Invoice" sheet
  // Change the reference of the cell or the name of the sheet if it is different
  const value = ss.getSheetByName("M-Generate").getRange("F3").getValue();
  const email = value.toString();

  // Subject of the email message
  const subject = ss.getSheetByName("M-Generate").getRange("B3").getValue();

    // Email Text. You can add HTML code here - see ctrlq.org/html-mail
  const body = "Automated Quotation - Sent via Auto Generate from Glideapps";

  // Again, the URL to your spreadsheet but now with "/export" at the end
  // Change it to the link of your spreadsheet, but leave the "/export"
  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zgs1jzjIeaBpd5Ms7emQgxhVJBMtlEOlDNDfxlhSRiY/export?';

  const exportOptions =
    'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + // export as pdf
    '&size=A4' + // paper size letter / You can use A4 or legal
    '&portrait=true' + // orientation portal, use false for landscape
    '&fitw=true' + // fit to page width false, to get the actual size
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + // hide optional headers and footers
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' + // hide page numbers and gridlines
    '&fzr=true' + // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    '&gid=101637384'; // the sheet's Id. Change it to your sheet ID.


      const exportOptionss =
    'exportFormat=xlsx' +
    '&gid=1200037229'+
    '&gid=101637384'+
    '&gid=557878560';// export as pdf
  
    // You can find the sheet ID in the link bar. 
  // Select the sheet that you want to print and check the link,
  // the gid number of the sheet is on the end of your link.
  
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  
  // Generate the PDF file
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions, params).getBlob();
  var responsee = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptionss, params).getBlob();
  
  // Send the PDF file as an attachement 
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [{
            fileName: ss.getSheetByName("M-Generate").getRange("B3").getValue().toString() +".pdf",
            content: response.getBytes(),
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        },{
            fileName: ss.getSheetByName("M-Generate").getRange("B3").getValue().toString() +".xlsx",
            content: responsee.getBytes(),
            mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
        }]
    });

  // Save the PDF to Drive. (in the folder) The name of the PDF is going to be the name of the Company (cell B5)
  const nameFile = ss.getSheetByName("M-Generate").getRange("B3").getValue().toString() +".pdf"
  const folderID = "1SHKAXCyXmNMwv1QKPYW0QCwey-yzpJih";
  DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID).createFile(response).setName(nameFile);
}


function on_sheet_change(event) {
  var sheetname = event.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  
  if (sheetname == 'M-Email Me') {
    emailSpreadsheetAsPDF() ;
  } else return;
}
```

Comment: do a copy:paste.special values to get rid of the formulae.

Comment: i mean how to do using script

Comment: @SolarMike i  mean how to do using script ?

Comment: Have you looked at the vba code on here for several similar questions? Can be a very good start.

Comment: @SolarMike I'm not sure what you meant. but the script that i have above is just to export . What i need is copy paste the value & formatting before its export( using apps script)

Comment: At what point does it become `#N/A.`?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Rather than give a lot of clarifications, it will help a lot to show your imput and expected output to understand your problem.